# Is there a way to run multiple JVM within the same browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, java, jvm

I'm using Oracle at work which fires off a Java app. I'd like to use two instances of the same app to work between two different screens of the same app. I can do it but with Chrome opening one and a second browser (Internet Explorer) opening other. Can I do this within Chrome? Tried Incognito mode but with no luck.

Comment: Depends on your app and how it saves preferences I suppose - I run multiple instances of my Oracle Forms (JVM based) app on different tabs